# onListItemClick callback isn't activated

Tags: android, list, listactivity

```
public class List_Items extends ListActivity{

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

       List <ImageAndText> total_list=new ArrayList<ImageAndText>();

           ListView lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

       lv.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new ImageAndTextListAdapter(this, total_list));

       getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

              //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sync);
      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast message=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click the list_item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            message.show();}
      });
       }

  public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
  {         
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected " +(position+1)+"th item",
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

}

I have this list_item which is extends the listactivity. However, when I click on one of the row, the callback onListItemClick didn't get activated.   Why is that? I don't need to anything with the adapter on this right?

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following in **all the widgets of xml which you are inflating** for your custom ListView.

```
android:focusable="false"

android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @lilzz...this happens as having a focusable item in a row of a ListView causes the OnItemClickListener or onListItemClick NOT to be invoked. Thats why we have to make focussable false

Answer (score 1):

u havent register ur onItemClick with Listview.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            Log.i("List Clicked ....", "List Clicked...");          
        }
    });
```

**or**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
public OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Log.i("List Clicked ....", "List Clicked...");      

    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think that this is required. As you can see his class extends a ListView, infact he can override public void onListItemClick. What are you doing is required if you are extending a normal Activity and you have a list in the layout

Comment: so what...bt u have not registered onClick of Listview.untill and unless u wont register it how will it be called ?????

Comment: As I said this is not a normal Activity but a ListAcivity so by default I think that it's already done the binding. Infact it provides directly the @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  Log.i("You clicked the list");
}
```